# Mongoose: Sort by nested field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to sort the data with nested field, called `orderIndex`.

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  Book.find({ _id: req.params.id })

    .sort({ 'Book.chapters.orderIndex': "asc" }) //doesn't work

    .then(books => {
      res.render("books/index", {
        books: books
      })
    });
});
```

Example of what a `Book` looks:

```
//Book
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "1234517fe46cf86900af82f"
        },
        "chapters": [
            {                 
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "a1"
                },
               "title": "first book",
               "orderIndex": "1",
            },
             {                 
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "5678798be6bb05e4427ee65"
                },
               "title": "second book",
               "orderIndex": "2",
            },
            //..some more
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change

```
.sort({ 'Book.chapters.orderIndex': "asc" })
```

To

```
.sort({ 'chapters.orderIndex': 1 })
```

Take a look at this [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#modify-the-cursor-behavior)

Here the [`sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) documentation.

Comment: Unfortuantely this is not working for me :/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64673548/sort-query-results-based-desc-value-of-nested-subdocument-within-array-mongoose