# Sort query results based desc value of nested subdocument within array Mongoose/Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My documents look like this:

```
{
 { 
    mlsId: 'RTC749',
    firstName: 'Tommy',
    lastName: 'Davidson',
    officeMlsId: 'RTC2421',
    officeName: 'John Jones Real Estate LLC',
    slug: 'tommy-davidson',
    serviceAreas: [
    {
      name: 'Nashville',
      slug: 'nashville',
      type: 'city',
      totalClosedSales: 3
    },
    {
      name: 'Franklin',
      slug: 'franklin',
      type: 'city',
      totalClosedSales: 7
    }
  },
 {
    id: 'RTC7280',
    firstName: 'Jack',
    lastName: 'Miller',
    slug: 'jack-miller',
    serviceAreas: [
    {
      name: 'Nashville',
      slug: 'nashville',
      type: 'city',
      totalClosedSales: 4
    },
    {
      name: 'Franklin',
      slug: 'franklin',
      type: 'city',
      totalClosedSales: 10
    }
  ]
 },
}
```

The query to find documents based on slugs within the subdocuments looks like this:

```
    const localAgents = await Agent.find(
      {
        'serviceAreas.slug': locationSlug,
      },
      '-_id -__v'
    )
      .sort({ 'serviceAreas.totalClosedSales': -1 })
```

Note that I'd like to find agents by location slug and sort the result using `totalClosedSales` however I'm unable to get it to work. So the desired result would look like this:

```
{
  {
    id: 'RTC7280',
    firstName: 'Jack',
    lastName: 'Miller',
    slug: 'jack-miller',
    serviceAreas: [

    {
      name: 'Franklin',
      slug: 'franklin',
      type: 'city',
      totalClosedSales: 10
    },
    {
      name: 'Nashville',
      slug: 'nashville',
      type: 'city',
      totalClosedSales: 4
    }

]
  },

 { 
    mlsId: 'RTC749',
    firstName: 'Tommy',
    lastName: 'Davidson',
    officeMlsId: 'RTC2421',
    officeName: 'John Jones Real Estate LLC',
    slug: 'tommy-davidson',
    serviceAreas: [
    {
      name: 'Nashville',
      slug: 'nashville',
      type: 'city',
      totalClosedSales: 3
    },
    {
      name: 'Franklin',
      slug: 'franklin',
      type: 'city',
      totalClosedSales: 7
    }
    ]
  },
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't sort array directly, But aggregation helps it

- `$unwind` helps to de-structure the array
- `$sort` helps to sort as you wish
- `$group` helps to re-group the de-structured array

Mongo script is given below

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "serviceAreas.slug": "nashville"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$serviceAreas"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "serviceAreas.totalClosedSales": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      total: "$serviceAreas.totalClosedSales"
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      total: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      mlsId: {
        $first: "$mlsId"
      },
      firstName: {
        $first: "$firstName"
      },
      lastName: {
        $first: "$lastName"
      },
      slug: {
        $first: "$slug"
      },
      serviceAreas: {
        $push: "$serviceAreas"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jC9PKwxRaAl)**

Comment: Im not trying to sort the arrays themselves. My goal is to sort the entire result by values (totalClosedSales) of the subdocuments.

Comment: so you need to sort a particular documents which are matched with ` 'serviceAreas.slug': locationSlug`  only? what is locationSlug here?

Comment: `locationSlug` is the slug key on the subdocument. So in this example it would be a query for 'franklin'

Comment: does https://mongoplayground.net/p/lXtABNdq-nL help you?

Comment: not really, I'm also trying to replace what you have with my query and I keep getting => error in query: fail to parse content of query: invalid character ')' after array element

Comment: What is the problem you face in the above query?

Comment: Your query sorts the arrays themselves. The query I need should simply sort the results based on value of the subdocument within the arrays (which it does not do at the moment)